# Springboot- reload property values without server restart

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reload, application.properties

I have a springboot application and an application.properties file from which the values get fetched when the application runs. I am finding a solution to change the property values and reload it without server restart.

Using spring-cloud-config is a solution I know, but I cant use the cloud config in our application . Please suggest if there is any other way to reload the property files using springboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `archaius` available at `https://github.com/Netflix/archaius`.

Here is how you use it.

```
DynamicStringProperty property = getDynamicPropertyFactoryInstance()
    .getStringProperty(key, StringUtils.EMPTY);
```

You will have to create a wrapper now to read all values from config.properties file. Archaius reads and returns updated values from `config.properties` file by default.